# getting a cocos2d sprite image path

Tags: objective-c, string, image, cocos2d-iphone

How could I get the image file path of a sprite in string form in cocos2d?

Are there any classes or methods that specifically do this? The easiest and simplest way would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question needs a better explanation, it's ambiguous. What path? Recent movements or tracing the shape of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must get texture of sprite (`CCTexture2D` or `CCTextureAtlas`). It would be value for some string key in `CCTextureCache` `textures`. This key is your path.

As I see in Cocos2d, `CCTextureCache` has no property/method to access its textures, so you need to expand this (for example in category):

```
@interface CCTextureCache (getTexturePath)
-(NSString*) getTexturePath: (Texture2D*) texture;
@end

@implementation CCTextureCache (getTexturePath)
-(NSString*) getTexturePath: (Texture2D*) texture
{
    return [[[textures allKeysForObject: texture] lastObject];
}
```

@end

So, to get path for some sprite:

```
NSString* path = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] getTexturePath: [mySprite texture]];
```